# Dynamic generation for submitted forms: $event->getData() returns null

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to add a city to a User class that extends the BaseUser from FOSUserBundle, and i'm following the guide in this page:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data

I've made a RegistrationType class, with the following code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    /* i setted a name field just to check that this form builder is used then i try to create a user */
    $builder->add('name');
    $builder->add('provincia', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'         => 'AppBundle\Entity\State',
            'placeholder'   => '', #
        ));

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();

            $data = $event->getData();

            $state = $data->getState();
            $cities = null === $state ? array() : $state->getCities();

            $form->add('city', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'       => 'AppBundle\Entity\City',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choices'     => $cities,
            ));
        }
    );
//...
}
```

The thing is that when it throws me an error in $data->getState(), it tells me "Error: Call to a member function getState() on null".
What could be happening?

Comment: Can you show us how you declare your form in your controller?

Comment: Hi Raphael, i think i'm not declaring a form, because for what i understand from the fosuserbundle documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html) all i have to do is to create a class that inherits from the bundle's RegistrationFormType, declaring:
public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

My whole class would be:
(look at response below, i cant put all the code here because of chars limitation in this response)

Answer (score 0):

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
      $builder->add('name');
      $builder->add('state', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'         => 'AppBundle\Entity\State',
            'mapped'        => false,
            'placeholder'   => '', #
        ));

        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, State $state= null) {
            $cities = null === $state? array() : $state->getCities();

            $form->add('city', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'       => 'AppBundle\Entity\City',
                'placeholder' => '-Choose a state-',
                'choices'     => $cities,
            ));
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $data = $event->getData();

                if($data === null || !method_exists($data, 'getState')) {
                    $formModifier($event->getForm(), null);
                } else {
                    $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getProvincia());

                }
            }
        );

        $builder->get('state')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
                // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
                $state = $event->getForm()->getData();

                // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
                // the parent to the callback functions!
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $provincia);
            }
        );
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

What really drives me mad is the fact that $event->getData(), which should bring something according to the official doc example, in my case comes null. I've managed to work around this registration form to work, but now i'm having the same problem with the profile edit form argggghhhhh